# internal-ip with Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, ip

I tested the `internal-ip` npm package with Angular 13 and everything worked fine and I was able to get the correct IP address.

Then I tried to integrated it into my Angular 11 project and it keeps giving me these error messages:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using below

```
//declare this in the index.html as script src
https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=**getMyIP**

//declare this in the index.html as script function
function getMyIP(json) {
  localStorage.setItem("<<your key>>", json.ip);
}
```